# required input validation in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I'm trying to validate a required input that must not be empty.

```
    <input
        type="text"
        id="task"
        name="task"
         [(ngModel)]="newTask"
          (keyup.enter)="addTask()"
          class="form-control form-control-lg"
          #task="ngModel"
          required
         placeholder="Add new task and hit enter key">

         <div *ngIf="task.invalid && (task.dirty || task.touched)"
         class="alert">
       <div *ngIf="task.errors?.required">
         Task is required. 
       </div>
  </div>
```

what  should i add in the ts file so that no empty input gets submitted?

Comment: Remember error message will be shown after user blur textbox once.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `newTask` field into your component class and everything will work fine.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-4vjm42?file=app/app.component.ts).

**app.template.html**

```
  <input
        type="text"
        id="task"
        name="task"
         [(ngModel)]="newTask"
          (keyup.enter)="addTask()"
          class="form-control form-control-lg"
          #task="ngModel"
          required
         placeholder="Add new task and hit enter key">

         <div *ngIf="task.invalid && (task.dirty || task.touched)"
         class="alert">
       <div *ngIf="task.errors?.required">
         Task is required. 
       </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public newTask: string = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is part of a reactive form, you can use validator require() function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        newTask: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
}
```